# QR Code code inserting '[' and ']', how to stop this?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, qr-code

I'm trying to loop through a list of ~3,000 URLs and create QR codes for them.  In one column I have the URLs and in another column I have what I want the QR code file names to be named when output as images.

The problem is the URLs that get converted to QR codes and my file names both come out encased in brackets.

For example:

```
URL            Filename
www.abel.com   Abel
```

Comes out as:

```
URL in QR Code   Filename of QR Code
[www.abel.com]   [Abel]
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import csv
import qrcode
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('QR_Python_Test.csv')

i = 1
x = df.iloc[[i]]
 
print(
x.QR_Code_Name.values)
for i in df.index:
    z = df.iloc[[i]]
    x = str(z.Link_Short.values)
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=5, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,box_size=5,border=2,)
    qr.add_data(x)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image()
    file_name = str(z.QR_Code_Name.values) + ".png"
    print('Saving %s' % file_name)
    image_file = open(file_name, "w")
    img.save(file_name)
    image_file.close()
file.close()
```

And some sample data:

```
URL               Filename
www.apple.com      Apple
www.google.com     Google
www.microsoft.com  Microsoft
www.linux.org      Linux
```

Comment: Your sample data doesn't appear to be a csv file, and nothing in your code appears to produce the output you give for 'Comes out as'.
Anyway, calling `str()` on both of the values looks like a big red flag: my guess would be that you've got a list rather than a single value, possibly because you called `df.iloc()` with a list, but as I know nothing about pandas that's just a guess.

Comment: @Duncan, my file is really a CSV file, I just put some data up there to be helpful.  I use Pandas the most so that's why I'm importing it that way, if the usual Python 'read_CSV()' is the right solution I'm game for it - and if not using Pandas at all is the right way to do this that's OK, I want to know the right way to do this.  Thanks for your comment to help me clarify things, Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataFrame contains the correct information, you can use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples)

also separate the functions

- reading the data from the file
- generating the qr-code
- saving the files

That way, you can test each of these individually

```
def generate_images(df):
    for row in df.itertuples():
        yield row.Filename, generate_qr(row.URL)

def generate_qr(url):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=5, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,box_size=5,border=2,)
    qr.add_data(url)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    return qr.make_image()

def save_qr_code(qr_codes):
    for filename, qr_code in qr_codes:
        filename = filename + '.png'
        print('saving to file %s' % (filename,)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            qr_code.save(file)

df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')

qr_codes = generate_images(df)

save_qr_code(qr_codes)
```

Comment: I made a couple of small changes, i.e qr.add_data(x) to qr.add_data(url) to get the final code to work, but the expertise in this was certainly yours.  Thank you!